# Jquery UI window does not display the button "Yes"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Just want to get confirmation of user before deleting the photo. I use Jquery UI dialog window. The code below displays the window correctly but WITHOUT "Yes" button. Could you please have a look on the code and help me to find my mistake.

```
   $( "#aaa").text("Do you want to delete the photo?");
    $( "#aaa").dialog({     
            modal:true,
            draggable:false,
            buttons: [{text: 'Yes',
                      click: function() {  
                      // delete photo  
                      },                
                      text: 'No',
                      click: function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
                     }]    
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one missing closing `}`:

```
buttons: [{text: 'Yes',
           click: function() {  } // <-------------- function closing
          }, // < ------------ object closing
          {                
            text: 'No',
            click: function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
          }]
```

or you can do this way:

```
buttons: {
         'Yes': function() {  },
         'No' : function() { $(this).dialog('close');  }
         }
```